# Make a Procedure with components

Tags: delphi

I have a program with 10 grids. Also i have a tms Ctyptogrpahy pack. I need a simple way to encrypt the cells , save the grid , and the to decrypt again so to continue to use it.

Every time i want to save one of the grids i have to do this

```
for r : 0 to grid1.rowcount-1 do
for c : 0 to grid1.colcount-1 do
grid1.cells[c,r]:=encode.encrypt(grid1.cells[c,r]);
grid1.savetofile('name.van');
for r : 0 to grid1.rowcount-1 do
for c : 0 to grid1.colcount-1 do
grid1.cells[c,r]:=encode.Dencrypt(grid1.cells[c,r]);
```

I need a procedure or function to be like 
savegrids (gridname:string ; gridfilenme:string);

i tried it with Tadvstrgrid(findcomponent(gridname) but dont let me use components inside a function or procedure.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please replace the code in your q by a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This makes little sense to me. Maybe something [like this](https://pastebin.com/V2RVJkBF)?

Comment: You did not show the error you are getting. But `FindComponent()` is a non-static method of `TComponent`, so I'm guessing you are not calling it on a `TComponent` object anymore after you move the code into a procedure. You need to call `FindComponent()` on the `TForm`/`TFrame` object that owns the Grid, assuming you drop the Grid at design-time rather than create it at runtime. Also, you are calling `FindComponent()` way too many times. Call it once and save the result into a local variable, then use that variable as needed.

Comment: @Remy, well, code like this would end up at least by missing `do` keyword for the loops (and maybe for misspelled control name `TAdvStrGrid`).

Comment: Please unlock the question .

Comment: Is what you are trying to ask how to write a method which will work with any TAvdStingGrid, not just, say, AdvStringGrid1 on your Form1?  If so, you could write smth like `procedure ProcessGrid(AGrid : TAdvStringGrid; const AFileName : String); var r, c : integer; begin for r := 0 to AGrid.rowcount-1 do for c : 0 to AGrid.colcount-1 do {etc} end;` and then use it by writing smth like `ProcessGrid(Form3.AdvStringGrid2)`.  Or, you could then write your `SaveGrids` by having it call SaveGrid for each grid you want to save.

Comment: Btw, it takes 3 people to vote to re-open & unlock the q.  I've voted to re-open it, because now it''s much clearer what you're asking, so onlu one more to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you have clarified what you are asking (following your edit), it is actually very straightforward to do.

By expressing your q in terms of using FindComponent, you had created an 'XY' problem which obscured what
you are actually trying to do.  It's usually better to ask 'How do I do X' than
to ask 'How do I do X by doing Y', because that assumes that Y will achieve X, but that may often be wrong.

Instead, to do what you want, you could write a method like this one

```
procedure SaveGrid(AGrid : TAdvStringGrid; const AFileName : String);
var
  r,
  c : Integer;
begin
  for r := 0 to AGrid.rowcount - 1 do
    for c := 0 to AGrid.colcount - 1 do
      AGrid.cells[c,r]:= encode.encrypt(AGrid.cells[c,r]);
  AGrid.SaveToFile(AFileName);
end;
```

Note that the main reason I've changed the name of the grid from grid1 to AGrid
is to avoid any confusion with any grid which may be on one of your forms.

Then, you could write a method to save several grids like this:

```
procedure SaveGrids(Grids : Array of TAdvStringGrid; FileNames : Array of String);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Length(Grids) - 1 do
    SaveGrid(Grids[i], FileNames[i]);
end;
```

and you could call this with something like

```
SaveGrid([Form1.AdvGrid1, Form1.AdvGrid2, Form2.AdvGrid1], ['SavedGridF1G1', 'SavedGridF1G2', 'SavedGridF2G1']);
```

Also note that I've written SaveGrid and SaveGrids as "stand-alone" procedures, that is they are not procedures of any particular form, so you could put them in their own separate unit and that would avoid the tangle of code you often get when you try to get one form to use the methods (procedures or functions) of another form.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was exactly what i need .